# Anyone using DynamoDB and Hive without using EMR?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-dynamodb, elastic-map-reduce

I was reading the below integration of using Hive for querying data on DynamoDB.
http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/01/aws-howto-using-amazon-elastic-mapreduce-with-dynamodb.html

But as per that link, Hive needs to be setup on top of EMR. But I wanted to know if I can use this integration with the standalone Hadoop cluster I already have instead of using EMR. Has anyone done this? Will there be sync issues between data in DynamoDB and HDFS happen compared to using EMR?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use it on your own cluster, you would need the custom **StorageHandler** for DynamoDB(it probably involves a custom **SerDe** as well).

It seems to be no available at the moment, at least not at AWS website.

What you can do is use the [JDBC interface](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/UsingEMR_Hive.html#HiveJDBCDriver), provided by Amazon, to produce the queries from your cluster, but it would still be executed on top of EMR.